# how can I avoid duplicating django sql queries when recursing

Tags: python, django, django-models

How to avoid duplicates during recursion in Django.
Django shows 12 duplicates with recursive sql queries, how do I avoid them, the code attached from below. Еhe task of the tag is to return the nested menu

[image]

```
class Menu(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True, db_index=True)
    parent = models.ForeignKey(
        'self',
        related_name='kids',
        blank=True,
        null=True,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )
```

```
class MenuView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'main/menu.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['main_menu'] = kwargs.get('slug', None)
        return context
```

```
@register.simple_tag()
def draw_menu(slug):
    menu = Menu.objects.filter(slug=slug).prefetch_related('kids') if slug \
        else Menu.objects.filter(parent=None).prefetch_related('kids')

    return menu
```

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block title %}{{ title }}{% endblock%}

{% block content %}
{% load draw_menu %}
{% draw_menu main_menu as menu %}
<ul>
     {% for item in menu %}
          {% include "inc/menu_by_menu.html" %}
     {% endfor %}
</ul>
{% endblock %}
```

```
<li>
    {% if item.kids %}
    <a href="{{ item.slug }}">{{ item.title }}</a>
    <ul>
        {% for kid in item.kids.all %}
            {% with item=kid template_name="inc/menu_by_menu.html" %}
                   {% include template_name %}
            {% endwith %}
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
    {% else %}
        <a href="{{ item.slug }}">{{ item.title }}</a>
    {% endif %}
</li>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to do prefetch two or three levels, which will likely be sufficient:

```
@register.simple_tag
def draw_menu(slug):
    qs = Menu.objects.all()
    qs = qs.filter(slug=slug) if slug else qs.filter(parent=None)
    return qs.prefetch_related('kids__kids')
```

Recursively prefetching could be implemented in Django, the queryset will need some updates, but at the moment is not the case. It is actually an interesting case that is not covered (yet).

Comment: thanks for the help, but the number of duplicates decreased by several, but did not disappear. Is there an alternative solution to the problem?

Comment: @DaniilFilippov: well adding an extra layer, so `.prefetch_related('kids__kids__kids')`. But as said, doing this recursively until all childs are "exhausted", is not yet possible.

Comment: I figured it out, but is this the right decision? If you add more code, you will need to add another layer of __kids and so on

Comment: @DaniilFilippov: well the best way to fix it, would be modifying Django's `query.py` to enable some "recursive" prefetching that will stop when there are no childs available anymore, or perhaps even better: make a recursive query to fetch the tree at once and then do the organization itself, but that is not possible. Perhaps take a look at `django-mptt` which has some work on tree-like dat.a